# What optimization algorithm is used within the .fit() method in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm curious what's 'under the hood' of `model.fit()` method from scikit-learn library? If it depends on a particular model, then let's say it's `linear_model.LinearRegression.fit()`.

Comment: Did you have a look in [GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I did but I couldn't find any relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

It is dependent on the particular model. Some methods have analytical solutions, like Linear-, Ridge- and Kernel Ridge regression. Some methods like neural networks use numerical solvers. In some cases the documentation has details on the exact methods used, or have options to set it yourself.